# convert data in json format

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

```
import enum
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd 
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}
r = requests.get("https://www.fleetpride.com/parts/otr-brake-drum-otr1601b")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
raw_json = ""
for table_index,table in enumerate( soup.find_all("script")):
    if('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"' in str(table)):
        x=str(table).split('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"')
        raw_json = "{\""+str(x[-1]).split('};')[0]+"}"
        break
      
      
req_json = json.loads(raw_json)
# uri = req_json.keys()

print(req_json)
```

this is my ouput show when I run code :

[image]

I want like theses in `json format` can it will be possible to convert in this format if possible can you tell how we convert in json form like these as you shown below I am grateful to you:

```
{
    "mediaWrappers": {
        "Alternate Images": [{
                "uri": "https://www.fleetpride.com/imagesns/PDPF/OTR1601B-Webb copy.jpg",
                "mediaName": "https://www.fleetpride.com/imagesns/PDPF/OTR1601B-Webb copy.jpg",
                "sourceType": "URI",
                "URI": "https://www.fleetpride.com/imagesns/PDPF/OTR1601B-Webb copy.jpg",
                "startDate": "2018-05-23",
                "sequence": 2,
                "productMediaId": "OTR-OTR1601B-Alternate Images-2",
                "mediaType": "Alternate Images",
                "locale": "en_US",
                "endDate": "2099-12-31",
                "enabled": true,
                "altMessage": "OTR OTR OTR1601B",
                "sfdcName": "406524",
                "sfid": "a8B1W000000c4a1UAA",
                "product": "a8G1W000000Y7DfUAK"
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both outputs are JSON formats. What you are looking for is called pretty printing. Read about `json.dumps()` and its options. You want to use the `indent` option.

```py
...
pretty = json.dumps(req_json, indent=4)
print(pretty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the following code after `json.loads()`.

```
with open("req_json.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(req_json, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: they show me `none`

Comment: they will give you output?

Comment: `json.dump()` is used to write to a JSON file, in this case `req_json.json`, while `json.dumps()` -- with s -- is used to convert a python object to a JSON string.

Comment: I misread and thought you wanted the file, especially because you open the json in a notepad, I'm sorry. If you want the pretty output in execution time use `json.dumps()` as @elmiomar said.